# Telerik GridViewSelectColumn - Map Checkbox To Boolean Property

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, telerik, radgridview

(I've looked far and wide for a Q&A before asking, but please forgive if it's already around somewhere else and I missed it.)

I'm just trying to do something that seemingly should be simple...  trying to map individual checkboxes in a `telerik:GridViewSelectColumn` in a `telerik:RadGridView` to a corresponding Boolean property of an entity mapped for each individual row.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyGridViewItems, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Extended" AutoGenerateColumns="False">    
    <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn Name="MyCheckBoxColumn">
        <telerik:GridViewSelectColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:GridViewDataControl}}, Path=DataContext.IncludeChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" IsChecked="{Binding MyBooleanProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        </telerik:GridViewSelectColumn.CellTemplate>                                            
    </telerik:GridViewSelectColumn>

    .
    .
    .

    </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

How do I map `MyBooleanProperty` to each individual checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to bind the `CheckBox` to a property of your data object, you should use a `GridViewCheckBoxColumn` or a `GridViewDataColumn`:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Name="MyCheckBoxColumn">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:GridViewDataControl}}, Path=DataContext.IncludeChangedCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                      IsChecked="{Binding MyBooleanProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

A `GridViewSelectColumn` does not bind to data. It simply allows you to select a given row.

Comment: What I am interested in doing is the de facto standard header checkbox, which will select/deselect all the row checkboxes.

Comment: Why are you then defining a CellTemplate? And how does your question of "How do I map MyBooleanProperty to each individual checkbox?" apply to this...?

Comment: I went off another example on Telerik's own forum. Their own documentation for what should seemingly be a standard feature is not only confusing, but leaves much to be desired.

Comment: All I want to do is have a header checkbox select all/unselect all, then be able to map the individual checkboxes - whether or not a user even bothers to click that header checkbox (which is a UI convenience) - into my list of entities. I don't understand why it should be so friggin' painful a thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

there is one solution as you have boolean variable `MyBooleanProperty` and you want to map it with every item of your list.
so what you can do is make one boolean property in your wrapper class itself `List<YourClass>`

class would be like this or something

`class Yourclass
{
bool ItemBool;
}`

now when you assign list just do `linq` and assign your `ItemBool` as per your condition